# How can I get EnumWindows to list all windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm assuming, what I'm asking should actually be the default, but I'm experiencing some behavior I don't understand.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(
  __in  HWND hWnd,
  __in  LPARAM lParam
) {
  if( !::IsIconic( hWnd ) ) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  int length = ::GetWindowTextLength( hWnd );
  if( 0 == length ) return TRUE;

  TCHAR* buffer;
  buffer = new TCHAR[ length + 1 ];
  memset( buffer, 0, ( length + 1 ) * sizeof( TCHAR ) );
  
  GetWindowText( hWnd, buffer, length + 1 );
  tstring windowTitle = tstring( buffer );
  delete[] buffer;

  wcout << hWnd << TEXT( ": " ) << windowTitle << std::endl;

  return TRUE;
}

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] ) {
  wcout << TEXT( "Enumerating Windows..." ) << endl;
  BOOL enumeratingWindowsSucceeded = ::EnumWindows( enumWindowsProc, NULL );
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

If I invoke that code, it will list all minimized windows:
[image]

Now, I'm no longer interested in only the minimized windows, now I want all of them. So I remove the `IsIconic` check:

```
BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(
  __in  HWND hWnd,
  __in  LPARAM lParam
) {
  /*
  if( !::IsIconic( hWnd ) ) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  */

  int length = ::GetWindowTextLength( hWnd );
  if( 0 == length ) return TRUE;

  TCHAR* buffer;
  buffer = new TCHAR[ length + 1 ];
  memset( buffer, 0, ( length + 1 ) * sizeof( TCHAR ) );
  
  GetWindowText( hWnd, buffer, length + 1 );
  tstring windowTitle = tstring( buffer );
  delete[] buffer;

  wcout << hWnd << TEXT( ": " ) << windowTitle << std::endl;

  return TRUE;
}
```

Now I get all windows **except** the minimized ones (none of the previously listed window handles are listed this time):
[image]

For completeness, this is the `stdafx.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"


#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace std {
  #if defined _UNICODE || defined UNICODE
    typedef wstring tstring;
  #else
    typedef string tstring;
  #endif
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
```

### What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not combining both functions to get the desired result?

Comment: If I can't solve this, then I guess that's what I'll do. But I'm confident that there is a mistake in my code. And I would prefer to solve it.

Comment: My comment was a bit unqualified, sorry (had another thought about it) ;)

Comment: I assume you tried scrolling down?

Comment: @TonyK Yes, I adjusted the height of the window to fit the text for the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (as I assumed) not a problem with `EnumWindows` at all. The problem is with the output stream.

While debugging, I noticed that `enumWindowsProc` is called just fine for every window, but that some iterations are simply not generating output.

For the time being, I switched to using `_tprintf`, but I don't understand what the problem with the original code is. Calling `wcout.flush()` had no desirable effect either.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code? If you do, you may notice that there is still a code path where your callback function returns without printing anything.

Comment: Yes, after replacing the `wcout << ...` part with `_tprintf` everything works as expected. I must be using the stream incorrectly or something else is causing me this problem.

Comment: Using a debugger to examine the data in windowTitle for some of the "missed" windows might help you figure out the common denominator which should provide a hint as to the cause.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a callback function that lists all open windows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

static BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowCallback(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lparam) {
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
    char* buffer = new char[length + 1];
    GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer, length + 1);
    std::string windowTitle(buffer);
    delete[] buffer;

    // List visible windows with a non-empty title
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && length != 0) {
        std::cout << hWnd << ":  " << windowTitle << std::endl;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enmumerating windows..." << std::endl;
    EnumWindows(enumWindowCallback, NULL);
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to check if the window is minimized, you can use [`IsIconic()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527.aspx).

See Also:

- Microsoft: [EnumWindows function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx)
- Stack Overflow: [Getting a list of all open windows in c++ and storing them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42589826/3357935)

Comment: I think you forgot the `delete[]` statement... that can cause memory leaks

Comment: @MMD Good catch. Can you suggest that as an edit?

Comment: This solution doesn't compile in Visual Studio 2022. Even if the issue with casting char* to LPWSTR is fixed, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

Well, `wcout.flush()` never works, however `wcout.clear()` fixes your code, at least for me.

```
wcout << hWnd << TEXT( ": " ) << windowTitle << std::endl;
wcout.clear();
return TRUE;
```

And I know that this question is already one year old, however it's never too late to answer.

Comment: You're right, this works. However, after looking up the documentation for `ios::clear`, I'm a bit confused in regards to *why* it works.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of Windows (dunno its accuracy) says that EnumWindows only enumerates top level windows. If you wish to enumerate child windows, you need to use EnumChildWindows function where you have to pass handle of parent window