# how to get name of opened form names in window application

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to display list of opened forms in windows application(windows forms) c#. can anyone tell me how to store open form names and display it ....
i need display like below

e.g

open form names

- form1
- form2

how to do it. can anyone help me...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

var names = Application.OpenForms.Cast().Select(f => f.Name);

Comment: Looks like a poorly formatted duplicate of Sergey's answer.  I wonder why this two-year-old question recently had this answer added, and then three days later selected as correct.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection:

```
var names = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Select(f => f.Name);
```

If you want types of opened forms, then select `f.GetType().Name`

Comment: its showing like this   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Windows.Forms.Form,System.String]

Comment: @Happy yes, that will be collection. You can create list of names with `names.ToList()` or you can create string with all names `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, names)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want system wide you can use EnumWindows to get all top level windows, your question isn't clear about exactly what you're after.

[How can I get EnumWindows to list all windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246444/how-can-i-get-enumwindows-to-list-all-windows)