How do I get a list of open GUI Applications on Windows using Delphi?
I'm trying to make a form that works similarly to the Discord Share Application Screen feature as can be seen here:

With a button click, I'd like to be able to list all the running applications on my computer that have a window (GUI) that I can capture, but I'm not sure how to get such a list.
I've tried some random code that I've found online, but nothing that really works for me yet. Ideally, I'd like a simple function that I can call that returns a list of the apps with all relevant info. I think what I basically need is the name of the application and possibly the handle (HWnd) for it, but I haven't been able to find or write such a function yet.
How can I get such a list of running GUI applications on Windows using the Delphi programming language?

This is kind of what I've written so far to try and do it. I've been trying with the EnumWindows function, but it's obviously not working yet  and I'm also very new to the WinAPI. So I don't really know how it works, but this is what I've got so far:
uses Winapi.Windows;

...

type
  TWindowObject = record
    Handle: HWnd; // Window Handle
    Caption: String; // Window Caption Text (If any)
    ProcessID: Integer; // Process the window belongs to
    IsVisible: Boolean; // Is the window visible?
    IsEnabled: Boolean; // Is the window enabled for mouse/keyboard input?
    IsIconic : Boolean; // Is the window minimized?
    Dimensions: TRect; // Window Dimensions
  end;

...

function GetListOfRunningGUIApps: TArray<TWindowObject>;
  var
    TempResult: TArray<TWindowObject>;

  function WindowCallback(WHandle: HWnd; var Parm: Pointer): Boolean; stdcall;
  begin
    var MyWindow: TWindowObject;

    MyWindow.Handle := WHandle;

    var MyString: String;
    GetWindowText(WHandle, PChar(MyString), GetWindowTextLength(GetForegroundWindow));
    MyWindow.Caption := String(MyString);

    var ProcessID: Integer := 0;
    MyWindow.ProcessID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(WHandle,@ProcessID);

    MyWindow.IsVisible := IsWindowVisible(WHandle);

    MyWindow.IsEnabled := IsWindowEnabled(WHandle);

    MyWindow.IsIconic := IsIconic(WHandle);

    MyWindow.Dimensions := Rect(0,0,0,0);
    GetWindowRect(WHandle,MyWindow.Dimensions);

    TempResult := TempResult + TempResult;

    Result := True;
  end;
begin
  EnumWindows(@WindowCallback,LPARAM(Result));

  Result := TempResult;
end;

And then on my button click, I have the following right now to call that function:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  var Apps := GetListOfRunningGUIApps;
  for var I in Apps do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(I.Caption);
  end;
end;


You tagged the question with [tag:firemonkey]. This task is very platform-specific, there is nothing in FireMonkey to handle this for you. You will have to use platform-specific APIs. For instance, on Windows, try the Win32 EnumWindows() and IsWindowVisible() API functions (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246444/)

@RemyLebeau I tagged FireMonkey as that is what I'm using, but I know that I need to use Windows-specific APIs for the Windows platform. I'm wrapping them in compiler directives. I also found the EnumWindows one and I'm currently busy playing with it to try and get it to work, but haven't been able to succeed yet.

Then THAT is what you should have asked about, specifically.  StackOverflow works better with specific questions.  You should [edit] your question to include what you  have already tried that is not working for you

@RemyLebeau I've tried lots of different things already though and I wasn't sure what is even correct or not. So I wasn't even sure if EnumWindows was the correct function or not. I'll update it shortly, maybe with a code example as well for what I've done so far with EnumWindows .

@RemyLebeau Okay. I've edited my question and shown what I've written so far for the EnumWindows one.

@AmigoJack "you should be interested in knowing the class name of each window (GetClassName()), since that will never change over its lifetime (in contrast to its title)" - that is not guaranteed. Sometimes the class name is changed from one version of an app to another. Maybe the user updates an app and now your code breaks because it is looking for an outdated class name.  So, just something to be aware of.

@RemyLebeau I do this for decades and it virtually never happened - by "lifetime" I primarily meant that of a process/instance and only secondarily the whole installation/version. The window title needs much more care - one example is Delphi's IDE: the title is different as per loaded project. But there are also programs with indifferent class names (like TApplication and #32770).

@AmigoJack A prominent example of volatile window class names is the Windows Forms library. Class names are dynamically generated whenever the corresponding class is registered. Executing the same binary twice will create the same windows with different class names. The bottom line is this: Neither EnumWindows() nor FindWindow() can be used to reliably identify a window.

There are a lot of issues with your code:

TArray probably isn't the best choice, since you would have to keep reallocating it as you iterate through the windows, which is inefficient at best. Consider using TList<TWindowObject> instead, which uses memory more efficiently. But that is beside the point.

WindowCallback() should be a standalone function, not a nested function. This code WILL fail at runtime if you compile it for 64bit.  You cannot use a nested function as an API callback in 64bit, like you can in 32bit.  See Why cannot take address to a nested local function in 64 bit Delphi?

the signature of WindowCallback() is wrong. The 2nd parameter should not be a var, and it should be an LPARAM not a Pointer. And the return type should be a Win32 BOOL (aka LongBool), not a Delphi Boolean.

you are misusing GetWindowText().  You are not allocating any memory for it to write to. And you are passing it a text length that is being obtained from the completely wrong HWND to begin with.

GetWindowThreadProcessId() returns a thread ID.  You are ignoring the process ID it gives you via its 2nd parameter.  Also, the 2nd parameter expects a pointer to a DWORD not an Integer.

you are not actually adding your TWindowObject instances to the TArray at all.  You are appending the array to itself instead, and since the array is empty to begin with then the array ends up remaining empty.


With that said, try something more like this:
uses
  ..., Winapi.Windows;

...

type
  TWindowObject = record
    Handle: HWnd; // Window Handle
    Caption: String; // Window Caption Text (If any)
    ProcessID: DWORD; // Process the window belongs to
    IsVisible: Boolean; // Is the window visible?
    IsEnabled: Boolean; // Is the window enabled for mouse/keyboard input?
    IsIconic : Boolean; // Is the window minimized?
    Dimensions: TRect; // Window Dimensions
  end;

  TWindowObjectArray = TArray<TWindowObject>;

...

function WindowCallback(WHandle: HWnd; Parm: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
type
  PWindowObjectArray = ^TWindowObjectArray;
begin
  var MyWindow: TWindowObject;

  MyWindow.Handle := WHandle;

  var MyString: String;
  SetLength(MyString, GetWindowTextLength(WHandle));
  SetLength(MyString, GetWindowText(WHandle, PChar(MyString), Length(MyString)+1));
  MyWindow.Caption := MyString;

  MyWindow.ProcessID := 0;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(WHandle, @MyWindow.ProcessID);

  MyWindow.IsVisible := IsWindowVisible(WHandle);

  MyWindow.IsEnabled := IsWindowEnabled(WHandle);

  MyWindow.IsIconic := IsIconic(WHandle);

  MyWindow.Dimensions := Rect(0,0,0,0);
  GetWindowRect(WHandle, MyWindow.Dimensions);

  var MyArray := PWindowObjectArray(Parm);

  SetLength(MyArray^, Length(MyArray^)+1);
  MyArray^[High(MyArray^)] := MyWindow;
  // or: MyArray^ := MyArray^ + [MyWindow];
  // or: Insert([MyWindow], MyArray^, MaxInt);

  Result := True;
end;

function GetListOfRunningGUIApps: TWindowObjectArray;
var
  TempResult: TWindowObjectArray;
begin
  EnumWindows(@WindowCallback, LPARAM(@TempResult));
  Result := TempResult;

  // or simply:
  // EnumWindows(@WindowCallback, LPARAM(@Result));
end;


Thanks Remy. Your answers are always great! I'll properly go through it tomorrow and test.

@ShaunRoselt Does the solution work for you?
